# MySQL Paramatirzation not working using mysql.data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

The following is my code it does an insert into the database but the values are not parametrized.

http://pastebin.com/h04UhcYv

Everything just shows up as null.

Comment: no need to put "C#" in the title, since it's in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Parameters.Add() try using Parameters.AddWithValue(), for example:

```
        using (MySqlConnection oCon = new MySqlConnection("connectionString"))
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES(@column)";
            MySqlCommand oCom = new MySqlCommand(sql, oCon);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", "value");
            oCon.Open();
            oCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oCon.Close();
        }
```

Seems your code it's fine but also you can check what DLL version of MySql.Data you are using, and the value that you are sending to the procedure.

As a bit of advice, the connection object should be opened just before the command is executed, also it's a good practice to use the statement *using* as this will dispose the object after termination.